# How to replace all 2-space groups with a tab character in Sublime Text?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, regular-language

I want to convert a file which was indented using 2 spaces into one which uses tabs. How do i specify this regular expression *replacing*?

I can find the regular expression with this: `/^(  )+/`
But how do i now replace each 2-space groups with a tab?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using SublimeText for this task?

Comment: Then there is no answer as there is no "generic" regex. Every regex flavor is different. The task is easy to complete in SublimeText. However, it won't work in Python `re`, in JS, in sed...

Comment: Isn't there a feature in Sublime Test to convert tabs to spaces and visa versa?

Comment: **Your question is much general. Please be more specific**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SublimeText3 uses PCRE regex engine, thus you may use the following regex replacement:

*Find*: `(^|\G)`   (or a bit more visible `(^|\G)[ ]{2}`)
*Replace*: `\t`

The `(^|\G)` matches the start of a line (`^`) or document *or the end of the previous successful match* (`\G`), and the    (= `[ ]{2}`) will match 2 regular spaces.

[image]